# Clear Unwanted Namespaces with LibXML-Ruby

Tags: xml, ruby, xpath, namespaces, libxml-ruby

I would like to parse an Atom Feed and create an Atom-compliant cache of each Entry.

The problem is that some feeds ([this one for example](http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user/04362720645292707297/state/com.google/starred)) have many namespaces other than the Atom one.

Is it possible to keep intact all Atom nodes and remove each node that belongs to another namespace?

Something like this:

```
valid_nodes = entry.find('atom:*', '/atom:feed/atom:entry')
# now I need to create an xml string with valid_nodes, but how I do that?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT you could use this transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:if test="
      namespace-uri() = ''
      or
      namespace-uri() = 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    ">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()|comment()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This copies all nodes verbatim, if they are

- in the default (empty) namespace
- in the Atom namespace
- text nodes or comments

Maybe you can use that.